# Bind label text inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, gridview

I saw few grid view examples where data is bound to grid view from a sql or other database. The question is -

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="label1"  runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("name") %>'>  
    </asp:Label>  
</ItemTemplate>
```

How is `Text='<%#Bind("name")%>'` working? From where does the label gets the text?

I am using `mysql` I have a drop down list of tables, and a button. Whenever the user selects any table from ddl, and clicks on the button, I will bind the selected table with the grid.

I have enable `autogenerating=true` for edit and delete buttons.

I will write code for that, but whenever the user selects a different table will the grid show edit and delete buttons? and what about the `Bind("value")` ? will it change for every table?

Might be a silly question but please help!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0 might help you

Answer (score 2):

The `#Bind("name")` command will insert the value of the column named `name` from whichever table you're binding to the GridView. Therefore, each of your tables would need a column named `name` for this label to be populated.
Also, `#Bind` should be used for both displaying and updating data. If you only need to display data, `#Eval("name")` is a better choice, as this is read-only.

Comment: @Netricity- what if every table is not having column name `name` . How can i bind the name of table selected by user in ddl? and how do i allow the user to insert a new record? because grid allows to edit,update and delete. what about inserting new record?

Comment: Perhaps just set the GridView's `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` then you don't need to use #Eval at all or define any ItemTemplate? It depends how much you need to customise the display. Alternatively, expose your tables' data as classes that implement a common interface?

Comment: @Netricity- yes i have set `AutoGeneratecolumns="true"` and the grid is displaying the data of every table selected by user. But how do i enable editing? because i think grid uses the id of the column to find which control triggered the event- `TextBox txtNewName = 
          (TextBox)grdContact.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewName");`

Comment: but that can be done only when i know the exact column name and bind it in `<ItemTemplateField>`. Now i will not be knowing the column names, so i have just added a check box in my grid. Rest all is autogenerated. Because of this i cannot find which check box was selected. So i'm unable to find a way to fix it.

Comment: I think i can add a `<TemplateField>` programatically. I can get the column count from `GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count` then i will loop throgh and add a `<TemplateField>` but then again, i have to add a `<ItemTemplate>` then label inside that. Also a `<EditItemTemplate>` with Text box.  Can i do all that programatically ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the `#Eval`, for example,

```
            <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbleditusr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Username") %>'/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
```